# Easy share action is not working in WebView Android app

Tags: android, webview, share

I have been trying almost everything to get this share button to work. The button is placed right but it's not getting clicked and the share window is not showing. 
Secondly, I want it to share Web URL of the page when clicked and I am also unable to understand how to do that.

Moreover, I do not want the button to be hidden in the Action settings. I want it to be displayed on the top bar, that's what's my main problem is.
MainActivity.java

```
    package com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView YoWeb;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });
        LoadWeb();
    }

    public void LoadWeb() {
        YoWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = YoWeb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        YoWeb.loadUrl("http://www.yoalfaaz.com");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        YoWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            //onPageFinished Method
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Hide the SwipeRefreshLayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (YoWeb.canGoBack()) {
            YoWeb.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
        return shareIntent;
    }
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

First, the button is not clickable.
Second, how to share the current page URL?
These are the two queries which I am unable to solve.

Comment: The method setShareIntent is never called. Since you share menu does nothing, it is not the button that is not being clicked, it is the button that does nothing.

Comment: @jonathanrz can you tell me where should setShareIntent be called and how. I am kind of beginner here and confused to get it running.